# How to automate UI of vscode extension

Tags: selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, functional-testing

I have a VScode extension which is created by my team, which also has UI to enter arguments once function has written in the extension and I need to automate the functional test for that. I need to know which tool, package I can use to automate the same.

Steps to automate:

1. Open extension in vscode
2. Create project using that extension
3. Click on details icon of project
4. Verify the Details page (UI) opened for the that project
5. Enter arguments on the details page
6. Click on execute button on that UI
7. Verify message

Note: When we click on details icon of a project, it opens UI for the project created using extension in VScode itself

Already checked below link but had issues installing this
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/11/18/new-tools-for-automating-end-to-end-tests-for-vs-code-extensions/

Comment: what is the use of the numbered list, it is the test you need to write, so unimportant for the question, only confuses. Have you read the VSC extension testing pages?

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to automate VS code extension using playwright and gitpod OpenVSCode server to automate. refer: https://medium.com/modern-mainframe/test-automation-with-playwright-for-vs-code-extensions-facilitating-the-growing-interest-in-dcc463f81efa.
https://github.com/gitpod-io/openvscode-server

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).