# Can I programmatically control / script Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, automation, applescript

I use AppleScript in my Mac for automating various processes in my computer. I know that Visual Studio Code does not have an AppleScript dictionary.

Is there any way to programmatically control Visual Studio Code eg using Python or any other programming language?

As an example I would like to programmatically get the path of the frontmost document.

I know that VSC has a [JavaScript API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api) . Can I use this for automation purposes?

Comment: you can write VSC extensions, what do you want to do with the `path of the frontmost document`

Comment: My final aim is to create automatically a link to the current point of the cursor in the active file.

This link should look like that: ```vscode://file/{full path to file}:line:column```

So I need to automatically get at least the current path and line.

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70660381/9938317

Comment: Thank you very much rioV8, it does solve the specific problem and I did not know at all about VSC tasks. 

However, I think VSC would benefit by providing a more obvious / less complicated / conventional way to automate things using a single script file and for example JavaScript.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64352471/how-to-automate-ui-of-vscode-extension)

Answer (score 3):

I guess a lot of such automation / programmatic control can be done via the [JavaScript extension API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api).

There is `vscode.window.activeTextEditor`, and that gives you `document.fileName` or `document.uri` for the filename, and `selection.active` to get you the cursor position ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65261663/vscode-how-to-get-position-of-cursor-in-the-document)).

It looks like this API allows for a lot of automation, e.g. [moving cursor around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65248766/does-vs-code-extensions-api-support-changing-cursor-position), [inserting text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65625230/insert-predefined-text-at-cursor-position), etc.

There is [vscode-ext](https://vscode-ext.readthedocs.io/) ([active fork](https://github.com/Nicholas-Schaub/vscode-ext)) to write Python extensions. When you look at the code, you see that this provides a websockets bridge from JavaScript inside VSCode to Python in a separate process. This bridge could be use for controlling VSCode from some external process.

Further, I just learned about the [Robot Framework](https://robotframework.org/) / [Robotic Process Automation (RPA) Framework](https://rpaframework.org/) (also with Python backend). I'm not sure but it might be helpful.